# Can't check svn file revision

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't do a merge with svn.

I have called "MyProject".
I have a repository with the trunk/tags/branches tree.
Inside my truck folder I have a folder called "MyProject", with my

- truck

  - MyProject

    - src
    - pom.xml
- branches

  - branchName

    - src
    - pom.xml

When I try the merge, I receive the following message : "'/svn/... (my url) .../brancName/MyProject' panth not found: 404 Not Found"

I understood that Intellij is looking for a folder with the name of the project inside the branch URL, instead of looking the directly content of the branch, someone have a suggestion on how can I solve that? I'm struggling for a while now with that

Comment: Can you describe what exactly did you do to get this problem (Steps to reproduce)?

Comment: Of course. I'm trying to merge the branch to the trunk using the "Merge From..." option located in the "Subversion Working Copies Information" menu. I'm doing this operation from the trunk working copy

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have "MyProject" in "BranchName" you have to merge from "BranchName" to "trunk/MyProject" isntead of merging to "trunk".

Comment: Sorry Andrej, but I just can't see how can I do that in Intellij. I hope my english didn't make you understand my problem in the wrong way. I want to integrate the branch changes to the trunk.I can't find an option that let me apply the changes directly from the branch to the trunk

Comment: I never did it with  Intellij, I used Tortoise SVN. I think the branch was created in a wrong way: "MyProject" directory should have been created in the branch also. Did you also use Intellij do create the branch or you created in in some other tool?